# Is there a readily available (or at least not theoretical) material that reflects only infrared light?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, material-science

By way of context, please picture those little motion capture lights that are put over an actors body.  I am interested in finding out if there is some kind of material that can do the same thing but *only* reflect infrared or, maybe UV, light.

Comment: Glass with IR-reflective coating (such as indium tin oxide (ITO)) is easy to find. You could potentially cut out little pieces of that.

Answer (score 1):

For UV, have a look at this site:
http://www.decoypaint.com/

Similar products seem to exist for IR - look for solar roof coating.

If you want real suggestions you probably need to define your needs a bit more - although this is pretty off-topic already.

Comment: Thanks, but this is closer to what I am looking for:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uNyQW29xGA.  So I guess that answers the question.  If you would like to drop this link in the body of your answer, I would be happy to select it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ordinary black materials reflect or are transparent in infrared light, especially plastics..

It's a real pain building infrared instruments to find something that's actually black in some bands.